# Match hex color code in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

I've looked around a little bit and I can't seem to find a working way to verify(in regex) if a given argument is a hex color code. Here is my code that I have:

```
echo `expr match "$1" '\(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})\)'`
```

When I put it into a file (hex.sh), it returns nothing whereas it should return the code itself. Am I wrong or what should the code be?

Comment: what is *a given argument* ?

Comment: I'd run it as a bash file, so I'd do something like this: sh hex.sh "#542541"

Comment: You don't need to capture the output to pass to `echo`; that construct works because `expr` *already* writes to standard output. `expr match "$1" '...'` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***expr match "$string" '($regexp)'***

curly brackets `{}` and *"pipeline"* character`|` as well as regular brackets `()` should be escaped within `$regexp` argument.
Use the following adjustment:

```
#!/bin/bash/
echo `expr match "$1" '\(#[A-Fa-f0-9]\{6\}\|#[A-Fa-f0-9]\{3\}\)'`
```

Test output:

```
$ sh hex.sh "#542541"
#542541
```

Comment: @BraxtonFair, glad to help